# Saving personalized view of a custom page in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have created a custom page in SharePoint online and there are different widgets  which can be dragged and dropped on different zone on the page based on the user preferences. But if we refresh the page the view that user created is not saved and the page again appears with the default position of the widgets.

So I wanted to know if there is anything we can do to save the changes made by the user on page and when he comes back, he sees the same view again..

Comment: did you publish the page after changing the position of these widgets ?

Comment: No, it is just a webpart page where in content editor I have jquery code to drag and drop widgets.